# Adding A User to a Role Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception, roles

I am trying to add a user to a role using the following code but the UserManager always returns a NULLReferenceException. Any tips for how to get this to work. I feel like it should not be that hard.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {



        ApplicationUser user = cd.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var account = new AccountController();

        account.UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, RoleName);

        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";

        // prepopulat roles for the view dropdown
        var list = cd.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Here is my account controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Owin;
using LaCeibaNetv4.Models;

namespace LaCeibaNetv4.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;

    }


    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string passCode)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid && passCode == "Fury")
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null) 
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return View("ConfirmEmail");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.");
                return View();
            }

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            // string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);       
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
            // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
    {
        if (code == null) 
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "No user found.");
                return View();
            }
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
                return View();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Disassociate
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
    {
        ManageMessageId? message = null;
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            message = ManageMessageId.Error;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Manage
    public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : "";
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Manage
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
    {
        bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        if (hasPassword)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
            ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
            if (state != null)
            {
                state.Errors.Clear();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LinkLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Account"), User.Identity.GetUserId());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/LinkLoginCallback
    public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), loginInfo.Login);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // SendEmail(user.Email, callbackUrl, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link");

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult RemoveAccountList()
    {
        var linkedAccounts = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = HasPassword() || linkedAccounts.Count > 1;
        return (ActionResult)PartialView("_RemoveAccountPartial", linkedAccounts);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && UserManager != null)
        {
            UserManager.Dispose();
            UserManager = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Helpers
    // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }

    private bool HasPassword()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.PasswordHash != null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void SendEmail(string email, string callbackUrl, string subject, string message)
    {
        // For information on sending mail, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
    }

    public enum ManageMessageId
    {
        ChangePasswordSuccess,
        SetPasswordSuccess,
        RemoveLoginSuccess,
        Error
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri) : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: dump the contents of cd.Users to trace, or view it in the debugger. There isn't a object that matches the predicate.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to Asp.net MVC. I dumped this contents of cd.Users and created another one but got the same error. Do I need to change something in the account controller to make it create the object?

Comment: By "dump" I mean display it on the screen. So let's imagine you are looking for user "Qbert", but the list of users you have is "Q-Bert", " Qbert ", "q b e r t" and "Q63r+". None of them will match. Verify that you don't have a data problem before you suspect a code problem. I can see you code, I can't see what data or parameter values you have.

Comment: Also do a null check like `if (user != null) { account.UserManager.AddToRole .. }` so you will not get the `NULLReferenceException` if there is no matching record found. As Matthew suggests you will have check the data why it returns null.

Comment: The user is definitely not NULL. I made sure it is not a data problem. For some reason the register action is not creating a new UserManager

Comment: are you sure that you are wanting to create a new `AccountController` for an instance of `UserManger`?  can you post the code of your `AccountController` here if so?

Comment: I posted the information.

Comment: You are calling empty AccountController() constructor. How would usermanager be available? Just call the overloaded AccountController constructor by passing usermanager as parameter.

Comment: Wow. You are right. I feel like an idiot. What am I supposed to add to it?

Comment: Best way is to call empty constructor itself, but let it call the other overloaded constructor. Make empty constructor as  public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))

Comment: I tried using the code you suggested but it does not work. ApplicationDbContext must have a return type and there are invalid arguments

Comment: this actually should work because the `get` method for UserManager does return `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()`, however I suspect that creating a new instance of a different controller for that one object doesn't make sense... if the UserManager is used in your controller, it should be defined there.  Aside from that, creating it within the controller that is using it will likely sort out the reason that it's coming back undefined.

Comment: How do I create a UserManager in a new controller? Also, can you post the answer in such a way that i can mark this question as answered?

Comment: at the moment we don't have an answer, only suggesting possible ways to narrow down what's actually gone wrong.

Comment: was this code copied from http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc?

Comment: yes! I was really stuck...am really stuck.

Comment: the code looks mostly correct, though this example seems to be a mix of concepts, in some parts using the user/role manager in other parts using direct Entity Framework calls.  without being able to debug the code myself, my best guess is that it's not the `UserManager` null, but that the role you are trying to add the user to doesn't exist.

Comment: The Role Does exist and it and I can see it and its key id in the database. All I really need to do is  add the user Id and accompanying role id to the ASPnetUserRoles table. Is there a way I can do that manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an Sql exception its.more likely the fields are returning a null value on post. Set a BP on your POST event and step through it and ensure your values are not null...

Also what's RoleAddToUser looks to me like your using identity. With identity there id a built in AddToRole so if that's a custom function am not really sure why ? You need to say what exactly is null. But my guess is your not sending the correct fields back.

Also if its custom just so you can do dropdown list of roles on my programme I just make the dropdown similar to what you did there but I do it in the login controller and ensure they cant select Admin.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this. what is your solution?

Comment: I was thinking more on the end off, your checking already if there null,and they obviously are as thats the issue happening, it always returns null. So maybe you have messed up the View fields where you input the data.

So does the issue happen on post back ? get ? is it an Sql error a coding error, a warning ? 

If its a warning and the codes working fine its probably just saying its possible it could be null and I would personally ignore it if all is working. But if user is nullable just check user.HasValue()

At a absolute cheat way get resharper and let that sort it out if its a real issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be getting error on the following line :

```
account.UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, RoleName);
```

at user.Id

You must check :

```
if (user != null)
```

then add User to Role.